# Database of all Ingress sentences

Tags: data-request, games

The Ingress game uses a limited set of human-generated sentences made from the Ingress vocabulary, which contains about a hundred words. Exemple of sentences:

- "XM Die Chaos Live"
- "Portal Have Truth Data"

I am looking for a database that contains all known Ingress sentences.
When linking to a database, please also mention how many sentences it contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

akiraak has compiled such a database:

https://gist.github.com/akiraak/b7c112e46b79dacfabf1

It contains 383 sentences.